# How to launch New Message window in Mail.app from my application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am able to launch Mail.app using the command
 [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"Mail.app"];

but I want to launch the new message window in Mail.app instead of whole Mail.app. How can I do so?

Answer (score 5):

I got the answer

```
 NSString *encodedSubject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SUBJECT=%@", [subject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *encodedBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BODY=%@", [body stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *encodedTo = [to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *encodedURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?%@&%@", encodedTo, encodedSubject, encodedBody];
NSURL *mailtoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedURLString];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:mailtoURL];
```